# How to add and get cookie value in Chrome with Selenium and Robot Framework

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, cookies, robotframework, selenium2library

I've been learning Robot Framework with Selenium2Library lately, and I've one little problem.

I try to Add cookie to website opened in Chrome, and then retrieve its value to make sure it's equal to expected value.

`resources.txt`:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${browser}        chrome
```

`cookieKeywords`:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          resources.txt

*** Variables ***
${CookieValue}    ${EMPTY}
${ExpectedCookieValue}    somevalue

*** Test Cases ***
CookieTest
    Open Browser    http://www.google.pl    ${browser}
    Add Cookie    CookieTest    somevalue
    ${CookieValue}    Get Cookie Value    CookieTest
    Should Be Equal    ${CookieValue}    ${ExpectedCookieValue}    "Cookie is equal"
    Close Browser
```

[image: Screen with project tree and error]

It looks like I can't add temporary cookies to website opened with chrome...

Maybe someone have occured the same problem?

Comment: I have just tested your code and it worked fine (also with Firefox). I even tried different URL, like https://www.google.com/. Just make sure you have the latest Chromedriver.

Comment: I've tried it on another computer and it worked, so I tried to reinstal Chrome and it worked, webdriver was still the same, so maybe version of browser was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Chrome browser helped :)